# Change icon set based on selected theme

Tags: wpf, theming

Suppose in my WPF program, I have created an option for the user to change the application theme (dark and light). What if I want to change all of the icons based on the selected theme? What's the best approach to do this?

Comment: Put all your images in a resourcedictionary and swap that upon theme change. Reference your images using `{DynamicResource}` throughout the UI.

Comment: @HighCore Could you make that to an answer and elaborate just a little more? Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide some example perhaps ?. Your question is a bit unclear to me

Comment: @OsmanEsen Suppose I have an application with bunch of forms, dialog, etc. There may be some icons used for menus, buttons... When I change the theme of the application I want to change the icons accordingly. For instance light icons for dark theme and dark icons for light theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dynamic resource for your image source like this:

```
<Image Source="{DynamicResource MyImageSource}" />
```

Then you can update the resource when the theme changes with this code:

```
Application.Current.Resources["MyImageSource"] = new BitmapImage(new Uri($"pack://application:,,,/Resources/{themeName}.png"));
```